# Deserialize XML with list of elements where some are xsi:nil=“true”

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

When I deserialize the XML below, from a third-party, my objects are always null.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OrderImport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Reply i:nil="true">
  </Reply>
  <ReplyStatus i:nil="true">
    <DebugInfo>
    </DebugInfo>
    <PerformanceLogInfo>
    </PerformanceLogInfo>
  </ReplyStatus>
  <Reply>
    <OrderNumber>4063286</OrderNumber>
  </Reply>
  <ReplyStatus>
    <Result>0</Result>
    <Message>
    </Message>
  </ReplyStatus>
</OrderImport>
```

**C# Class**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderImport")]
public class OrderImport
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Reply")]
    public List<Reply> Reply { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReplyStatus")]
    public List<ReplyStatus> ReplyStatus { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "i", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string I { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName= "Reply")]
public class Reply
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderNumber")]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReplyStatus")]
public class ReplyStatus
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DebugInfo")]
    public string DebugInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PerformanceLogInfo")]
    public string PerformanceLogInfo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the problem has to do with the first occurrence of the objects Reply and ReplyStatus being null.

I'm trying to deserialize like so

```
httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrderImport>().Result;
```

However, I've found that if I deserialize like this it works just fine

```
stringres = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
using (var stringreader = new StringReader(stringres))
                {
                    var result = (OrderImport)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);

                }
```

Comment: http is not designed to cast a string to an object which is why the first method doesn't work.  You need to use the xml serializer to parse a string to class objects.

Comment: `ReadAsAsync` with that overload would use `DataContractSerializer` by default, which should throw an exception given that XML & class (it would expect a different namespace). Are you able to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the first reply & reply status being null?